# How is a change of variables performed in Lotka-Volterra normalizations?

Tags: dynamical-systems

How is the change of variables really performed in Lotka-Volterra?

I'm trying to understand what happens in the following document:

[https://www.maths.dur.ac.uk/~ktch24/term1Notes(10).pdf](https://www.maths.dur.ac.uk/%7Ektch24/term1Notes(10).pdf), p. 17

I tried plugging the variables in, but I don't see how it produces the result.

Answer (score 2):

Start with the first equation

\begin{align}
\frac{{\rm d}x}{\rm {d}t} &= ax - bxy \\
\frac{{\rm d}(dx/c)}{{\rm d}t} &= a(dx/c) - b(dx/c)y & \text{multiply by } (d/c) \\
\frac{{\rm d}\hat{x}}{{\rm d}t} &= a\hat{x} - b\hat{x}y & \text{define } \hat{x}= dx/c \\
\frac{{\rm d}\hat{x}}{{\rm d}(at)} &= a\hat{x}/a - \hat{x}(by/a) & \text{divide by } a \\
\frac{{\rm d}\hat{x}}{{\rm d}\hat{t}} &= \hat{x} - \hat{x}\hat{y} & \text{define } \hat{t}=at \text{ and } \hat{y}=by/a\\
\end{align}

you can use the same definitions of $\hat{x}$, $\hat{y}$ and $\hat{t}$ for the second equation, will leave that one to you

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thanks, just updated the answer

Comment: Why/how does one decide to multiply by d/c? It seems easy if one reads backwards in the notes, but if one starts from scratch, then "multiply by d/c" seems random.

Comment: Does one expect to make $\hat{x}-\hat{x}\hat{y}$? And then sees how to produce it? Progress variable by variable eliminating the leading coefficients?

Answer (score 2):

Let's try it from a slightly different angle: Decompose every variable into a constant scale factor and a "normalized" variable, $x=x_*\hat x$ etc. Then insert into the equations$\newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}$
\begin{align}
\frac{\dd(x_*\hat x)}{\dd(t_*\hat t)} &= a\,x_*\hat x-b\,x_*\hat x\,y_*\hat y\\
\frac{\dd(y_*\hat y)}{\dd(t_*\hat t)} &= c\,x_*\hat x\,y_*\hat y-d\,y_*\hat y
\end{align}
Now remove the scale factors from the left side and collect the scale factors
\begin{align}
\frac{\dd\hat x}{\dd\hat t} &= (at_*)\,\hat x-(bt_*y_*)\,\hat x\hat y\\
\frac{\dd\hat y}{\dd\hat t} &= (ct_*x_*)\,\hat x\hat y-(dt_*)\,\hat y
\end{align}
Now set the combined coefficients to $1$ as long as that is possible:
$$
at_*=1\implies t_*=\frac1a,\\
bt_*y_*=1\implies y_*=\frac{a}{b},\\
ct_*x_*=1\implies x_*=\frac{a}{c},\\
dt_*=\frac{d}{a}=\hat d\text{ has no free parameter},\\
$$
This gives the normalized system
\begin{align}
\frac{\dd\hat x}{\dd\hat t} &= \hat x-\hat x\hat y\\
\frac{\dd\hat y}{\dd\hat t} &= \hat x\hat y-\hat d\,\hat y
\end{align}

---

The other variant to simplify the second equation is to have both coefficients equal, so that the resulting factorization and thus the stationary points is/are normalized.
$$
ct_*x_*=dt_*\implies x_*=\frac{d}{c}.
$$
The normalized system is then
\begin{align}
\frac{\dd\hat x}{\dd\hat t} &= \hat x-\hat x\hat y\\
\frac{\dd\hat y}{\dd\hat t} &= \hat d\,(\hat x\hat y-\hat y)
\end{align}

Comment: I don't understand what happens at: "remove the scale factors from the left side and collect the scale factors"

Comment: You multiply the equations by constants so that on the left side none of the scale factors $t_*,x_*,y_*$ remain. Then sort the factors in the products on the right side.

Comment: Ahh now I see...

Comment: And to go back to the original, one does what?

Comment: You multiply the scale factor back, $t=t_*\hat t$, $x=x_*\hat x$, $y=y_*\hat y$.